# Jquery time picker not working if a control inside a div how is display none

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-timepicker

i am using Jquery plugin "Timepicker" with fancybox, the div where i place text box for time picker is display none, fancy box automatically pop out that div,

the problem is, Time picker is not working inside that div.
if i remove "display:none" from style tag, its working fine,

can anybody help me out please ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try **visibility:hidden** attribute!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting display:none on the element itself, after you've called the timepicker function, try something like:

```
$('.element').hide();
```

But show us some of your code so we can see what you're trying to do :)